# Docker run for PostgreSQL fails because port already used

Tags: postgresql, docker

When I start PostgreSQL through Docker using this command:

```
sudo docker run --rm \
--name postgres \
-e POSTGRES_DB=mydb \
-e POSTGRES_USER=myuser \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="mypass" \
-e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata \
-v /etc/mydb/migrations/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ \
-v /mnt/mydb:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
--network host \
postgres:15.2-alpine \
postgres -c max_connections=1000 -c listen_addresses='0.0.0.0'
```

I get this error:

```
waiting for server to shut down...2023-04-17 21:00:17.231 UTC [38] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
.2023-04-17 21:00:17.231 UTC [38] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-04-17 21:00:17.232 UTC [38] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 44) exited with exit code 1
2023-04-17 21:00:17.233 UTC [39] LOG:  shutting down
2023-04-17 21:00:17.233 UTC [39] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
2023-04-17 21:00:17.243 UTC [39] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 950 buffers (5.8%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.010 s, sync=0.001 s, total=0.011 s; sync files=260, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=4431 kB, estimate=4431 kB
2023-04-17 21:00:17.258 UTC [38] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2023-04-17 21:00:17.372 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 12.2.1_git20220924-r4) 12.2.1 20220924, 64-bit
2023-04-17 21:00:17.372 UTC [1] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address "0.0.0.0": Address in use
2023-04-17 21:00:17.372 UTC [1] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2023-04-17 21:00:17.372 UTC [1] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "0.0.0.0"
2023-04-17 21:00:17.372 UTC [1] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
2023-04-17 21:00:17.378 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Prior to running Docker I don't have anything listening on port 5432:

```
$ sudo ss -tulpn | grep LISTEN|grep 5432
$
```

After running the command, I don't have anything listening on 5432 either.

My schema stored in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` gets applied, and after that I get the above message.

If I run the command a few more times, the command completes successfully and PostgreSQL is up and listening on port 5432

I'm running Docker on CentOS 7.

Comment: You can't combine `--network host` with port publishing (`-p host:container`). Pick one or the other (you probably want to drop `--network host` in almost all situations).

Comment: Thanks, I removed `-p 5432:5432`, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that if you attempt to connect to a database and query it before the database has come up, PostgreSQL thinks port 5432 is being used. We have container clients that attempt to connect to the database, and on reboot we don't have control on how the containers come up. The solution was in our clients, after connecting to the database, call [Ping()](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.Ping) to check if the database is actually up before continuing.